# POWERQUERY : Deal with a column containing Text Values and Table

Tags: powerquery

I am dealing with a column which is having Text Value mixed with Table data.
Table value

[image]

I would like to operate on this column by

- if value = Table : aggregate the Table by combining the value with a comma separator
- if value =  : keep the original value

The result would be

[image]

I use this function to aggregate the value for Table, but I got an error when the value is a text
= Table.AggregateTableColumn(#"Lignes filtrées1", "value.1", {{"Element:Text", each Text.Combine(List.Transform(_, (x) => Text.From(x)), ", "), "Desired Result"}})

Would you have some tips to help me with this problem ?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is hard to tell what you have in your table

As an example if the embedded table looked like this, with a single column

[image]

then you could add a column like

```
#"Added Custom" = Table.AddColumn(#"PriorStepName", "Custom", each try Text.Combine([Column1][TableColumn1],",") otherwise [Column1])
```

and get

[image]

If your table is more complicated you'd probably have to unpivot it first or otherwise give us a hint how to transform it into a single cell